# Use Angular js with datatable js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, sorting, search, datatables

I am new for both [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) and [datatable](https://datatables.net).

I am creating ASP.NET MVC Application using this two js and want to display records in the table.

Table displays the records but searching and sorting facility is not available I mean not running. I don't know how to integrate both to use in one page.

Can anyone help me to come out from this problem?

Code:

I have $scope.Customers which has fields Name, Phone , Email and more...

```
 $scope.getCustomers = function () {
        customerService.GetCustomers()
        .then(
            function (response) {
                console.log("Get Customer call");
                $scope.Customers = response.data.Result;
            }
        );
    }
```

Here I got the list of customers and binded successfully and my HTML code is:

```
<table id="tblcustomers" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered no-margin">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Active</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="cust in Customers track by $index">
                                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditCustomer(cust)">{{cust.CustomerName}}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Adddress_Line_1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Phone}}</td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Email}}</td>
                                    <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == true"><span class="icon-check2"></span></td>
                                    <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == false"><span class="icon-close"></span></td>
                                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="DeleteCustomer(cust)"><span class="icon-trash"></span></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

**output:**

[image]

**angular module:**

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("ANG", []);
})();
```

Comment: i think you need to attach the datatable plug in .. ddid you do it?

Comment: Please see this I have added bundle [like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290676/define-structure-of-asp-net-mvc-with-angular-js-and-theme/42290886) this.

Comment: ok..you include it..but you need to innitialize it and attach toyour table...try my answer maybe

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable.js filter data after the document is rendered completely.
Use DataTables settings after the document is rendered completely.
see demo here:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('testTable', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $('#tblcustomers').DataTable();
      });
    }
  }
});

var testCtrl = app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Customers = [];

  var i = 20;
  while (i > 0) {
    $scope.Customers.push({
      CustomerName: 'test' + i,
      Adddress_Line_1: 'testAddr' + i,
      Phone: '000-000-00' + i,
      Email: 'sample' + i + '@xxx.com',
      IsActive: true
    });
    i--;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DataTable test for Angular</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table id="tblcustomers" test-table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered no-margin">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Active</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Active</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in Customers track by $index">
          <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditCustomer(cust)">{{cust.CustomerName}}</a></td>
          <td>{{cust.Adddress_Line_1}}</td>
          <td>{{cust.Phone}}</td>
          <td>{{cust.Email}}</td>
          <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == true"><span class="icon-check2"></span></td>
          <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == false"><span class="icon-close"></span></td>
          <td><a href="#" ng-click="DeleteCustomer(cust)"><span class="icon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: datatable's usecase show the usual way: initial the datatable in document.ready(). In angular, we have to use $timeout to do things that after document.ready().

Answer (score 0):

have you troed something like to put in a  directive the datatables initialization?

something like:

```
    "use strict";

angular.module("ANG")
    .directive("grid", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                $timeout(function () {

                    $(element).DataTable();
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

and then use it like:

```
<table id="tblcustomers" grid class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered no-margin">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Active</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="cust in Customers track by $index">
                                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditCustomer(cust)">{{cust.CustomerName}}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Adddress_Line_1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Phone}}</td>
                                    <td>{{cust.Email}}</td>
                                    <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == true"><span class="icon-check2"></span></td>
                                    <td ng-if="cust.IsActive == false"><span class="icon-close"></span></td>
                                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="DeleteCustomer(cust)"><span class="icon-trash"></span></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: which is you module name?

Comment: check now if it is ok..sorry :-)

Comment: yep ..but chekc if it works now ... if not..try to put your id instead of elemen..so something like: $('#tblcustomers').DataTable();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135940/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-federico-scamuzzi).